# Understanding Password + Salting

Tags: security, encryption, passwords, salt

I'm having trouble understanding the benefits of storing user data in a database table using salting. The process I have set up is as follows:

1. User creates account with username/password
2. A random salt is generated.
3. Username stored in database, password encrypted and stored, salt stored along side password.

Now when a user attempts a login, they provide their username/password and:

1. Finds salt in database based on username.
2. Encrypts cleartext password provided using salt from database.
3. Compares the stored password and user provided password.

This is all fine and dandy, but doesn't a hacker merely have to guess the username and password combo? As long as they can determine a username, they can retrieve the salt. Using a brute force attack they would only need to determine the correct username/password combo. **The salt would be retrieved with just the username and added to the provided password in order to compare to the stored password, so whats the point of using the salt anyways?** Its not like the hacker has to guess the salt value. The password they provide is automatically encrypted with the salt from the database so as long as they know the username, its just a matter of guessing the password in cleartext.

Comment: It seems like in the scenario you're describing, the hacker has already gotten to the point where he/she can read the values in the database. In that case, the hacker doesn't need to bother with a brute-force attack, since they've already gotten to where they want to be (and you're already screwed). As David Schwartz says, the salt prevents rainbow attacks. In a similar vein, it also prevents a crooked DB admin from noticing that someone else has the same password hash as they do, and thus the same password.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm admittedly ignorant when it comes to hacking. I guess I just assumed they would write a script to hit a websites login form and start trying username/password combo one at a time a/a, b/a...aa/ab etc. Apparently thats not feasible.

Comment: No, that attack type IS quite feasible via cracker programs such as John the Ripper. Be sure to lock out a user account for twenty minutes or so after a certain number of consecutive failed login attempts (I use five failed attempts). Doing this significantly adds to the amount of time a brute-force attack would require to get into the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of the salt is to force the hacker to attack each username one at a time rather than allowing him to attack all of them at once. Because each username has a different salt, the very same password would be stored differently for it. This [defeats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table#Defense_against_rainbow_tables) a [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) attack.

Comment: So it basically just slows down the process? Makes it too costly?

Comment: It makes a rainbow table attack impossible. That means an attacker has to use some other form of attack which is likely to be much (billions of times, literally) less effective. An attacker can still try username/password combinations one at a time. Even this can be made difficult by using a computation intensive hashing function like [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: actually salting does not prevent the rainbow table attack, just make it harder: it all depends on the salt size. You can of course generate rainbow tables including the salt. E.g. for a 12bit salt your table size increases of a factor of 4096.